# Where to place Internal JS and External JS in HTML page

Tags: javascript, external, internal

I have used internal JS(on page) in my page which I write for my coding purpose. Along with it I use External JS too. I do use of External JS in my Internal JS(on page).  It works fine when I place External JS below my Internal JS. But It does not work when I place External JS above internal JS. I ask this for my knowledge. I just want to know reason. I know that.. JS should place at end of body tag. But what about when I use Internal as well as External JS.

---> If I define external js bellow internal js. Works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    script code .. which uses external.js function. 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
```

---> If I define external js above internal js. Does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     script code .. which uses external.js function.
</script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/JavaScript" src="yourfile.js"></script>  in case of external src can point to a url
eg .. <script  type="text/JavaScript" src="http://www.yahoo.com/some.js"></script>

Comment: I am not getting Explain me plz.

Comment: No matter what code is "external" or "internal". You should check only execution order. For example, if you define variable in first code piece, and use it in second code piece, you MUST place first before second.

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/external.shtml  this should help... and @Tommi is right it does not matter it is internal or external

Comment: Please try to frame the questions better for instant understanding of the issue, and if possible provide a code snippet as well

Comment: That's what I am saying. you are not getting me or some misunderstanding. I know .. @Tommi if variable define in 1st code piece and use in it 2nd code piece then it must place first b4 2nd. I have used external js but I use a function of external js in my internal js means on page. So I should define external js above internal js. but It does not work. If I define external js below internal js it works fine.

Comment: May be you have circular dependencies. Can you provide demo when page does not work? We can't say anything without sample. Also "does not work" is quite wide definition, browser usually have more meaningful exception text.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you will want to place scripts, internal or external, in the `<head>`.

Google Analytics [likes to be at the bottom of the page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingOverview#trackingCodePlacement) for reasons that make sense if you're slapping it onto an existing product. If you're designing scripts for a website from the get-go you have a chance to do it right.

Whether a script is internal or external is usually determined by whichever method makes more sense. If you have a script that is used on multiple pages you will likely put it in an external script so you can reuse it. Performance considerations are quite complex, it's certainly no trivial matter.

I guess what you're running into is some dependency of the external script on some internal script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var my_var = "foo";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>

-- external.js
console.log(my_var);
```

If you change the order of the scripts in the above example it will print `undefined` instead of `"foo"`.
Make sure you define your scripts in an order that makes sense. Make sure your external scripts don't have strange or undocumented dependencies.